# What does a.e. stand for?

Tags: meaning, abbreviations

While reading an article on statistics I stumbled upon:

[image]

Nothing in the previous text indicates what the meaning could be.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Statistics. Presumably there is a relevant SE where it could be asked or migrated to — CrossValidated?

Comment: Did you google "mathematical abbreviations a.e." or look at Wikipedia's comprehensive list of mathematical abbreviations?  I did that; took me literally 15 seconds to find [*almost everywhere*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_everywhere). Do please take a whack at researching your questions before asking here. Nothing elaborate. If you google and check a dictionary, thesaurus, or Wikipedia (as appropriate to the question), that is sufficient.

Comment: @DanBron No, I googled "a.e. meaning" and "a.e. abbreviation", none of which showed anything meaningful. I **always** do research before asking

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_abbreviations):

> a.e. - *almost everywhere*

The meaning of *almost everywhere* according to [Wolfram Math World](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AlmostEverywhere.html):

> A property of *x* is said to hold almost everywhere if the set of points in *x* where this property fails is contained in a set that has measure zero